# Finding the min and max values of a function and marking them on a graph using findmaximum/minimum

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, functions, mathematical-optimization

This is what i have so far to find the points that are zero and mark them on the graph. But i cant for the life of me figure out how to proceed. Only started using mathematica last week. I need to mark the min and max values of the function too. But i dont know how to find them.

```
enter f[x_] = x * Cos[π/6]*(x^5 - 2 x^3 + x) - 0.1;

solution = Solve [f[x] == 0];

zero = Table [{x, 0} /. solution];

Plot [Ekv[x], {x, -1.2, 1.2}, PlotRange -> {-0.12, 0.05}, 
Epilog -> {Point /@ zero}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The commands `FindMinimum[]` and `FindMaximum[]` are used to find local minima and maxima, respectively. In the current case, you can use `Solve` to get the stationary points directly.

```
 stationaryPoints = Transpose[{#, f /@ #}] &@(x /. Solve[f'[x] == 0, x])
```

Now, you can mark them on the plot

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -1.2, 1.2}, PlotRange -> {-0.12, 0.05}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[zero], PointSize[Medium], Red, 
   Point[stationaryPoints]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: This would help and it would give me what im looking for, but i have to be ready to explain what i have done and how i came to those conclusions. Which means dumbing it down and not using derivaties if possible seeing as thats something i dont really have a good grasp on